# USB device drawing too much power resulting in whining fan noise

Tags: macbook-pro, usb

I have suddenly started getting the error message and exactly the same time there is now a loud fan noise on the left side of my Mac Book Air.
I have tried the safe boot mode I have seen on other threads and the message has gone but the noise is still there.
Everything also now loads really slowly. I can't get a genius appointment until next week so if anyone can help that would be great!!

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting the SMC -- Apple recommends this if you are experiencing, among other things, fan and power issues, as well as slowdowns:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964